# Value from comma separated select option values and append the second value to a other select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

i'm struggling with a question, how i can get the value from comma separated select option value and append the second value to a other select option?
My html looks

```
<select id="firstSelecter_ID1">

<option value"first value, second value, third value">option1</option>
<option value"first value, second value, third value">option2</option>
<option value"first value, second value, third value">option3</option>
<option value"first value, second value, third value">option4</option>

</select>

<select id="secondSelecter_ID2">

<option value"second value">option1-a</option>
<option value"second value">option2-a</option>
<option value"second value">option3-a</option>
<option value"second value">option4-a</option>

</select>



    var entry6 = $('#Id_6')
    entry6.on('change', 'select#firstSelecter_ID1', function (e) {
...
    option value ,second .append() to #secondSelecter_ID2 as new option value =""
...
}
```

Many thanks if somebody can give me the idea and I hope I have asked the question right and understandable
Regards Maty

Comment: You'll probably need `val()`, `split()`, `push()` and `join()`

Comment: Thanks for your answer... this was what i think it also.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
$('#select_1 option').each(function(){
   var secondVal = this.value.split(',')[1].trim(),       
       $opt = $('<option>').val(secondVal).text($(this).text());    
   $('#select_2').append($opt);
});
```

Comment: Hi @charlietfl, this looks very useful. Thanks, i will try it out..
+1

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i got it to work how i need it...

```
    entry1.on('change', 'select#actiontypeSelect', function (e) {

    $("select#secondSelecter_ID2 option:eq(1)").remove();
    $("select#secondSelecter_ID2 option:last").remove();
    $('select#actiontypeSelect').each(function () {


        var value1 = $('select#actiontypeSelect').find("option:selected").val();

        var secondVal = value1.split(',')[1].trim(),
                $opt = $('<option>').val(secondVal).text('Exclusive Equipment');
        $('#secondSelecter_ID2').append($opt);
        console.log(value1);
    });
    $("select#secondSelecter_ID2").append('<option value="0.00">Inclusive Equipment</option>');
    e.preventDefault();

});
```

This gives me from the selected option the second value and append as a new option with the value to other select box.

Special thanks to @charlietfl he gives me the right way.